# List Search is not working in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-box

I am working in SP online.
I just realized that for some lists/libraries the search box is not working at all.

[image]

[image]

Suggestions? Remarks?

Thanks

Comment: WHat happens when you click `Include`? Are your items nearly identical?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this. I've tried re-indexing the List and have had no luck.. anything on your end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try redindexing the list: List Settings -> Advanced settings -> Reindex List

If there are multiple lists on same site affected you might want to index whole site: Site Settings -> Search -> Search and Offline Availability

Do note that in SPO it takes some time before reindexing kicks in so it might take some hours or a day until reindexing has full effect.

Comment: New items added to the site should appear in the index in less than 15 minutes.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Are you suggesting that the small green icon will disappear before one should expect indexing of that List Item?

Comment: The green icon has nothing to do with it. If you have not changed any of the default settings for search new items should show up in search results in less than 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem got solved by itself after 1 day. It seems MS takes some time to re-index lists. So next time I'll be waiting before alarming!

Comment: wjervis, between 15 minutes and 24 hours there is a difference. It is important to know that it is not just a question to take a coffee but wait one whole day.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by going to Site Settings > Site and offline availability > changed "Indexing Site Content" from No to Yes, then triggered "Reindex site" from that page.

Then I went to List Settings > Advanced Settings > "Reindex site"

And ten minutes later, the list items were appearing in search results.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me recently. Depending on the total items in the list or document library, you will have to WAIT for some hours. In my case, i have 62942 document in my document library, my user had to wait for like 12 hours for the page to properly re-index for the user. This usually happen when you just add the user to the list or document library. I hope this helps?

Comment: Was there anything special you had to do on your SP List to have the search box?  None of the lists that I create in SharePoint Online has the box and so no searches are happening.

Comment: @Holt Nothing. The searchbox is on every list you create. Check page top-center for the searchbox. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb5FT.png